# Spring JMS Subscriber not able to receive message?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm using Spring JMS and Web Sphere Default Messaging Provider for my Messaging Needs.
I have created a Topic and connection factory on WAS.

I am able to send message to Topic using `JMSTemplate` from my publisher.

But Whenever I call `JmsTemplate.receive()` in my Subscriber , it goes into waiting state and I am not able to receive message in my Subscriber.

However I am able to receive message in Subscriber using `JmsTemplate` if a use a Listener as Subscriber or if a start a new thread whenever I am publishing message using my Publisher.

Looking for help !

Answer (score 1):

Messages are not stored in the topic. If you create a Publisher, send messages ans then start a subscriber no messages will be subscribed. At the time of publishing if there are any subscribers subscribed to that topic then only those subscribers will receive the message. If no subscribers exist then messages will be dropped.

It goes into waiting state that means it is waiting for messages from the JMS server and there are no currently available.

Whatever mode of subscribing you are using - asynchronous(MessageListener) or Synchronous(receive) you need to create subscriber before.

You can use

```
subscriber.receive(long timeout);
```

if you do not want to wait indefinitely.

Comment: So if we are using Spring JMS in Synchronous mode ,then we need to call JmsTemplate.receive() in our subscriber before publishing on Topic by publisher.Is it so? So here our Subscriber will be waiting in a separate thread , then we have subscriber in another thread than Publisher . Is it so ? Please correct if I am wrong .

Comment: Yes! Subscriber will subscribe only to messages that are published after it becomes live. Unless ofcourse if it is a durable subscriber. In case of durable subscribers even if it is offline it will receive all the messages missed when it comes back online.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aniket !! So if we are using Spring JMS (Synch.) with non-durable subscribers , then we may not be able to implement Publisher and Subscriber in SINGLE THREAD . I mean I am not able to do that. Is it? Looking for your guidance !

Comment: No you cannot in single thread with publisher and async non durable subscriber. Because the way you run subscriber is probably call receive() in infinite while loop and that must be before you publish messages.

Comment: Thanks Aniket, your info is really helpful !!   If I am using SpringJMS simply without any Third Party Broker(like Actice MQ) and want to create durable Subscriber for both cases synch and asynch, then which configurations I have to make . Is there any link available ?

Comment: AFAIK SpringJMS is just an API. You will obviously need a JMS server to run you application. For providers you have open source options like Active MQ, Open MQ or HornetQ. I have not worked on SpringJMS so will not comment on it but you will definitely need a provider library.

Comment: ok. I am using Web Sphere default provider for JMS . Anyway ..Thanks a lot Aniket  for your support !!